# How do I configure glassfish 3.1 to use Websphere MQ7 for JMS?

Tags: glassfish, jms, ibm-mq

Maybe I dont know the right search terms to query with, but I cannot find instructions on how to configure glassfish 3.1 to allow me to use an external websphere mq7 server for my jms/mdb project. Can someone help me get this configured? I'll repay the community by writing a good howto document if there isn't one out there already.

Comment: Ohh, and I know about: https://genericjmsra.dev.java.net/docs/websphere-mq-integration-guide/webspheremq_integration_guide.html      but it makes no sense to me, I need step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this in my own semi-related Google search... didn't answer my question (nor did anything else) so I posted some instructions [here](http://seanc.us/blog/2012/06/20/resource-injection-of-a-websphere-mq-jms-topic-in-glassfish-v3/).

Answer (score 0):

You can download WebSphere MQ 7 client from IBM.
After extraction or installation you will find a websphere mq rar adapter which you can deploy onto glassfish. You can use this mq rar adapter to make connections to WebSphere MQ 7.

Comment: how do you use the MQ RAR to make connection to WebSphere MQ?  I think _that_ is the question.